# Linux - Bash - variable assignment with command substitution is missing the newlines

Tags: linux, bash, variable, command-substitution

I am running into a bit of an issue / quirk here:

```
[root@s06p5bcsmta001 elves]# TEST=$(cat -e sendlog)
[root@s06p5bcsmta001 elves]# echo $TEST | wc -l
1
[root@s06p5bcsmta001 elves]# cat sendlog | wc -l
1050
[root@s06p5bcsmta001 elves]# TEST=$(cat sendlog)
[root@s06p5bcsmta001 elves]# echo $TEST | wc -l
1
[root@s06p5bcsmta001 elves]# echo -e $TEST | wc -l
1
```

How do I get the contents of the text file (with \n) into the variable?

Comment: try `echo "$TEST" | wc -l`

Answer (score 1):

Yep - it was quoting...

```
echo "$TEST" | wc -l
1050
```

TY, Bodo!!